# Android Room what does @field mean

Tags: android, android-room

Im recently learning Room to manage my database and using "[GithubBrowerSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample)" as the template.

Generally, it looks good to me except for the @field keyword. I have been googling quite a bit but fail to find any explanation about it. Thee android doc examples seem to work fine without it. What is it really doing here in Room?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something unique to Room - instead this is [Kotlin Annotation targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets):

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode.

So `@field:SerializedName("owner")` means that the `SerializedName("owner")` annotation should be added to the underlying field itself (rather than say, when using `@get:` where it would attached to the generated `getOwner()` method or the `@property:` default which, as per that same page, isn't available to Java, which is what Room is parsing).

Comment: I still don't quite fully understand. Are you saying when kotlin code converts to java byte code, e.g. val name: String, it actually converts to three code snippet: 1. String name, 2. getName(), 3. setName().  And "@field" means to add annotation SerializedName("owner") only to the part "String name"? Am I getting the right idea?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Android Studio has a built in tool for [showing the generated code](https://link.medium.com/WVe6LItIb6) which you might find useful.